# filter files with a pattern and modified time

Tags: python, regex, file, filter

Hello I am using the below code to list the files in directory upon last modified time

```
searchdir = args[0]

files = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(searchdir)))
files = [os.path.join(searchdir, f) for f in files] 
files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))
print file
```

I would like to only list the files of specific pattern along with there last modifiedtime
How could i attain a specific pattern(filename) search in above code ? I would like to all the files with filenames Mtuberc ?

Examples files :

```
streptococcous.log 
baccidius.log 
Mtuberc.log  
Mtuberc.log.1 
Mtuberc.log.16
Mtuberc.log.13
```

expected Output :

```
Mtuberc.log  
Mtuberc.log.1 
Mtuberc.log.16
Mtuberc.log.13
```

Comment: Please tag your question: What is the programming language? Python?

Comment: @Ali Yes its in Python

Comment: OK, and I see you have tagged it accordingly. In the future please also include the tag for the programming language, it will help you getting an answer faster, it improves the visibility of your question. Good luck!

Comment: You could use either the [`glob` module](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/glob.html) to list only those files that match your criteria, or the [`fnmatch` module](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/fnmatch.html) to filter your list of files after you've collected them.

Answer (score 0):

The code below finds the files that match the given pattern. The pattern used requires that the filename starts with 'Mtuberc.log'.

```
import os
import re

searchdir = args[0]
pattern = re.compile(r'^Mtuberc\.log') # whatever you want to match
files = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(searchdir))
files = [os.path.join(searchdir, f) for f in files if pattern.search(f)] 
files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(x))
print files
```